# let $k$ be a field with characteristic $0$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq6}$. Prove the following statement

Tags: number-theory

let $k$ be a field with characteristic $0$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq6}$.

Prove that if $f,g,h \in k[x]$ with:

$f^2 + g^3 = h^n$ and $\gcd(f,g,h)= 1$

then $f,g,h$ are all constant.

I have seen a few of these questions in my textbook, and i think i need to use the abc conjecture or the contrapositive of maher stohers theorem.

maher stohers theorem:

let k be a field of characteristic $0$, then for all $a,b,c \in k[x]$ not all constant and $a+b+c = 0$ and $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$ we have:

$\max (\deg(a),\deg(b),\deg(c)) \leq \deg(rad(abc))-1$.

so in our case we get:

$\max(\deg(f^2),\deg(g^3),\deg(h^n)) \leq \deg(rad(f^2g^3h^n))-1$.

Am i supposed to try all degrees out and contradict this inequality?

I already tried two inequalities:

suppose $\max \deg = \deg(g^3)$, then:

$\deg(g^3) = 3 \deg(g)$.

but also $\deg(rad(f^2g^3h^n)) = \deg(rad(fgh)) \leq \deg(fgh) < 3deg (g)$. so $3 deg(g)<3deg(g)$ which is a contradiction!

suppose $\max \deg = \deg(h^n)$, With a same reasoning we get:

$n\cdot \deg(h) < 3 \cdot \deg(h)$. which is a contradiction since $n \geq 6$

I can't apply the same trick to $f$, so i am still thinking how to consider the case when deg (f^2) is the highest?.

Can one say that $f^2 = h^n - g^3$ so $\deg f^2 \leq \max \deg(h^n,g^3)$. Because then we get

Kees

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you get this problem from?

Comment: it was a test question, made by F.Beukers. I have seen varieties on these questions in his syllabus as well.

Comment: I am confused. Does the proof rely on the unproven abc-conjecture ? Or do we only need a case which has been solved ?

Comment: it relies on the mason stohers theorem i think, so i only need to get a contradiction with the last case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last inequality is almost the same. First notice that if max(deg($f^2$), deg($g^3$), deg($h^n$)) = deg(f^2) then we can conclude the following:

Deg($f^2$) = 2 Deg($f$) > 3 Deg($g$)  $\implies \frac{2}{3}$ Deg$(f) > $  Deg($g$).

2 Deg($f$) > n Deg($h$)  $\implies \frac{2}{n} $Deg$(f) > $deg$(h)$.

So now we want to show that Maher Stohers indeed doesn't apply. We find

2Deg$(f) \leq $Deg$(fgh) - 1 = $Deg$(f) + $Deg$(g) + $Deg$(h) - 1$

So

Deg$(f) \leq $Deg($g) + $Deg$(h) - 1 = \frac{2}{3}$ Deg$(f) + \frac{2}{n}$ Deg$(f) - 1.$

$n$ is chosen greater than 6. So

Deg$(f) \leq $Deg$(f) - 1.$

And that my friend, is just absurd.